# Showing that only solution that attains a value of $1$ is constant solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following ODE
\begin{align}
x'(t) = x(t)(1-x(t)^2), \ x(t) \geq 0 \  \forall  t,
\end{align}

I wish to prove that if a solution $x$ to the ODE attains a value $x(t') = 1$ for some $t'$, then $x$ is the constant solution $x(t) = 1$ for all $t$.

How could one go about showing it? Or is it not true?

---

I think this is true since after looking at numerical solutions (see image) with various initial conditions, it seems that all solutions are attracted asymptotically towards the constant solution $x = 1$ (other than the constant solution $x = 0$).

This makes sense, since when $0 < x(t) < 1$, we have $x'(t) > 0$, and when $x(t) > 1$, we have $x'(t) < 0$.

I am having trouble turning this intuition into a proof.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to be true we need to assume that the domain of definition is connected (I leave it to you to convince yourself that it is not true if we drop this assumption).

We consider the system
$$ (\star) =\begin{cases} x'(t) &= x(t) (1-x(t)^2) \\ x(t_0)&=1 \end{cases} $$
Note that the function $f(x)= x (1-x^2)$ is locally lipschitz and thus by the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem there exists a nbhd $(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+ \varepsilon)$ of $t_0$ such that $(\star)$ admits a unique solution $x(t)$. However, $\tilde{x}(t) =1$ is a solution of $(\star)$. Thus, we get by the uniqueness $x(t) =1$ for $t\in (t_0 - \varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)$.

Hence, if we have a solution $x$ of $(\star)$ which is defined on $ I:=(T_{-\infty}; T_\infty)$ (of course we assume $t_0\in I$). We define
$$ S:= \{ t\in I \ : \ x(t)=1 \}.$$
As $x$ is continuous we get that $S$ is closed. On the other hand we can pick $t_1\in S$, then $x$ solves 
$$ (\star\star) =\begin{cases} x'(t) &= x(t) (1-x(t)^2) \\ x(t_1)&=1 \end{cases} $$
and by the argument above we get that $x=1$ in a nbhd of $t_1$, which implies that $S$ is also open. However, $I$ is connected and thus we get $S=I$ which means $x=1$.

Comment: Hi Severin, I have not seen the notation $(T_{-\infty}; T_\infty)$ before. What does this mean?

Comment: Also, could you please explain in more detail why, after deducing that $S$
is both open and closed, and using the fact that $I$ is connected, that $S=I$? What theorems have been used here?

Comment: It $T_{\pm\infty}$ usually denote the maximal time of existence. That was the reason I called them that way. This is just notation, you can pick any interval you like that contains $t_0$.

Comment: A topological space $X$ is called connected iff for a closed and open set $U\subset X$ holds $U\in \{ \emptyset, X\}$ (ie the empty set and the whole space are the only clopen sets). So by the very definition of being connected we get $S=I$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a separable ODE which you should find has the variable solution
$$x(t)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{1+Ce^{-2t}}}\qquad C\in[-1,\infty)\setminus\{0\}$$
or the constant solutions
$$x(t)=0,\pm1$$
For $x(t)\ge0$ this leaves the only possible solutions as
$$x(t)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+Ce^{-2t}}}\qquad C\in[-1,\infty)\setminus\{0\}$$
$$x(t)=0,1$$
As you can see, the variable solution cannot equal $1$ for any $t$ as $e^{-2t}\ne0$ for any $t$. So that leaves a choice from the constant solutions, of which $x(t)=1$ is the only solution that has $x(t')=1$ for some $t'\ge0$.

Comment: $x(t)$ is restricted to being positive.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks, I've edited it.

Comment: Edited out the case of negative $C$ as that would imply a negative radicand as $t\to-\infty$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I was assuming that $t\ge0$ represented time from the OPs graph.

Comment: Ah okay. Well do as you want.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The OP has $x(0)=2$ which is not possible unless $C\lt0$.

Comment: A problem I have with this approach is that when we integrate $\int _{x(t_0)}^{x(t)} \frac{dx}{x(x^2-1)} = \int_{t_0}^t dt$, the integral on the LHS doesn't exist when the region of integration contains $1$. So by solving the ODE this way, it seems that we come up with solutions which don't pass through $x = 1$, by design.

To get this integral equation, we must divide by $x(x^2-1)$, which assumes that $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$ to start with, so it seems like we're assuming what we are trying to prove. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PeterForeman That would be true if we knew that all variable solutions can be found using the integral equation. How do we know this off the bat?

Comment: @EhWha How else do you suppose that we can find variable solutions? I believe that separation of variables identities all possible variable solutions when done correctly.

Comment: @PeterForeman I don't have other suggestions, just pointing out that when we use this method, we are imposing restrictions on our solutions (in this case $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$), and it's not immediately clear that we are finding all possible variable solutions. I think that you are correct, but it is still something to be proven, which is where my difficulty lies.

Comment: @EhWha It is also possible to find these solutions by solving the ODE via substitution which does not assume that $x\ne1$ but does require $x\ne0$.

Comment: The separation approach is valide. Assume that your solution is not identically equal to $0$ or $\pm1$ and pick $t_0$ such that $x(t_0)\neq 0,\pm1$. Then by continuity this also holds in a nbhd of $t_0$. Thus locally around $t_0$ our solution $x$ is of the form as stated above with the exponential. As long as your solution does not become zero or one we can extend this solution, but as noted this expression never becomes $0$ or $\pm1$ which implies that if the solution is not identically equal to $1$ it will never attain $1$.